# For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ find $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\setminus L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f/g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})?$

Tags: integration

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a strictly positive function. Can we then find a strictly positive function $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\setminus L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f/g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})?$

If $f^{1/2}\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we can take $g=f^{1/2},$ but I can't show the existence of such $g$ for the general case.

Comment: What happens when you try to show the existence of $g$ for the general case?

Comment: Well, if $f^{1/2}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$  then I could not find a "good" candidate that can be expressed in terms of $f(x)$ and tried to take $g(x)=1/(|x|+1)$ which didn't work.

Comment: When $f$ is particularly large, you probably want to set $g$ there to something that will suppress that largeness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : since your issue arises when $f^{1/2} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, you should try $g=\max(f^{1/2},\varphi)$ where $\varphi$ is a function which properties remain to be determined.

Comment: oh, thanks!It seems that $g(x)=\max\big(f^{1/2}(x),1/(|x|+1)\big)$ works.